# Color Time Series Based on The Cluster Assignment

Tags: matlab, plot, k-means

Say I have the following Time Series:

`a = [1 3 1 5 1 3 5 1 5];`

Now, on doing kmeans(a,3), I obtained:

`b = kmeans(a,3); // [1 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 3];` based on the clusters.

I now wish to plot a, so that the color for a(i) corresponds to the cluster that is has been assigned in b. Can someone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plots each point with increasing x coordinates, y coordinate equal to `a`, and the color as given by `b`:

```
colors = hsv(max(b)); %// or use other color maps: 
hold on
for ii = 1:length(a)
  plot(ii,a(ii),'marker', 'o', 'color',colors(b(ii),:)) %// option 1
end
axis([0 length(a+1) min(a)-1 max(a)+1])
```

[image]

Comment: Get this error :

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> GetKMeansPlot at 13
        plot(ii,a(ii),'marker', 'o', 'color',colors(b(ii),:)) %// option 1


But OK Otherwise

Comment: @gran_profaci It works for me with your example `a` and `b`. Have you checked that `b` has the same size as `b`?